# Why does Klogger fails to write the log file?

Tags: php, logging

While using KLogger, the file may be written correctly on a localhost machine, but may fail once the code is run from the external server.

Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The folder that will include the log file must have the permissions 666 or greater (but please do not use 777). Actually the only requirement is that the Owner has writting permissions.

Also ensure that you are pointing to the correct folder when you create the KLogger instance on this line:

```
$log = KLogger::instance(CONTRIBUTE_LOG_DIR, KLogger::DEBUG);
```

The string constant CONTRIBUTE_LOG_DIR must be valid.

Comment: Hmm. I have tried setting 666 but the log file wont write, when i set to 777 it writes.

I understand that i should use chown instead, and will use that, but cant understand why 666 isnt sufficient?

Comment: It should work, I can't imagine a reason why it does not work in your case. The best thing to do here (avoiding the 777) is to change the permission to 700 and then set the correct owner of the file, only one "7" is causing the file to work correctly.